# R - Compare longitude, latitude in two data frames

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I have two data frames df1, df2, containing longitude (lon) and latitude (lat) values.
For each row in df1, I want to calculate the geodesic distance (in miles) with each entry in df2 and return the number of entries with a distance less than say 30 miles.

What I have now seems to work, but is extremely slow:

```
    require(Imap)
    n30 = function(lon,lat) {
        d=apply(df2[,c("lon","lat")],1,FUN=function(x) {
            gdist(lon,lat,x[1],x[2],units="miles")})
        return(sum(d<=30,na.rm=T))  
    }
    df1$n30 = apply(df1[,c("lon","lat")],1,FUN=function(x) n30(x[1],x[2]))
```

Anyone have suggestions to speed this up?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide sample data with `dput(head(df1, 10))` and `dput(head(df2, 10))`. They way to work is do a cross join, then calculate distances the filter on those you want. Look at 'dplyr' package

Comment: Check out the `dist()` function in the `proxy` package.  It allows you to specify your own distance function.  You may be able to use it directly with the function you already have defined, `n30()`.